# Can we open the wizardpage directly using the buttons in the toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a eclipse plug-in project to implement an `IDE like eclipse`.

To create a file-I have two wizards to take the project name and the file name and other related information for the file I am creating. A `wizardPage` is followed after the two wizards which consists of widgets which asks for some information for the file that is created (say like in our eclipse to create a java class the gui has checkbox option asking for the user whether to include the main function or not).

What I need to do is when I m in my editor I need to open that wizardpage directly without going through the two wizards.

How can I do that?

Can any one help me in doing this? ?Because this is one of the main functionality the project guide has asked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly you want to launch a wizard on click of a button etc. To do that you could add a `Button` to your `Part` and call the Wizard via a `SelectionListener` on the Button like this:

```
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Open Wizard");
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(parent.getShell(),
            new MyWizard());
        if (wizardDialog.open() == Window.OK) {
            System.out.println("Ok pressed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancel pressed");
           }
    }
});
```